# CSS overlapping elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a website made in WordPress where I cannot edit any of the HTML - only add CSS and Javascript.

I have two elements, on of which is the content with text and an SVG image, the other is an `a` element that references a page on the site.

This makes the second element act kind of like a click box in my opinion. I drew the second element underneath the first and offset it by 100% of it's own height (they share the same height and are using 100% width of the parent container, in this case, the column.
Here is the HTML for the page.

```
<div class="wpb_wrapper">
                <style data-type="mBuilderInternal">
                    div.vc_column_container>.vc_column-inner.md_col-58ed434fd78d9{padding-top: 20px !important;padding-right: 20px !important;padding-bottom: 20px !important;padding-left: 20px !important;}
                </style>

    <style scoped="">
        .text_box-58ed434fd7a20{
            background-color: rgb(255, 221, 178);
        }

        .text_box-58ed434fd7a20:hover{
            background-color: rgb(238, 170, 85);
        }

        .text_box-58ed434fd7a20 .text-box-title,
                                         .text_box-58ed434fd7a20 .text-box-icon,
                                         .text_box-58ed434fd7a20 .text-box-description{
                                             color: rgb(80,80,80);
                                         }

        .text_box-58ed434fd7a20:hover .text-box-title,
        .text_box-58ed434fd7a20:hover .text-box-icon,
        .text_box-58ed434fd7a20:hover .text-box-description{
            color: rgb(255,255,255);
        }

    </style>

    <div class="text-box text_box-58ed434fd7a20 has-animation show-animation" data-animation-speed="600" data-animation-delay="0.0" data-animation-position="center" data-animation-show="once" data-animation-easing="Quart.easeInOut" style="transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px);opacity: 1;/* z-index: 1; */">
        <div class="text-box-content">
            <div class="text-box-icon-holder" style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px;">
                                    <div class="text-box-icon icon-Apple"></div>
                            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <!--End of Icon section-->

                            <h3 class="text-box-title" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 28px;"> Creative Design </h3>
                        <!--End of Title section-->
        </div>
                    <p class="text-box-description" style="opacity: 0;">##### produces a variety of specialty advertising vehicles. - Click to Read More</p>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <!--End of Description section-->
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $ = jQuery;
        if(typeof pixflow_textBox == 'function'){
            pixflow_textBox();
        }

            if ( document.readyState === 'complete' ){
        if(typeof pixflow_shortcodeAnimation == 'function'){
            pixflow_shortcodeAnimation();
        }
        if(typeof pixflow_shortcodeAnimationScroll == 'function'){
            pixflow_shortcodeAnimationScroll();
        }
    }

    </script>


    <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <a href="http://c6f.1d3.myftpupload.com/"><div id="Service1" class="linkedbox">
</div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
            </div>
```

That is all the raw HTML generated by the site, below is all the custom CSS I am using for this page.

```
div.linkedbox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: -1
}
div.wpb_raw_code {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0xp;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

And here is the little section of HTML added after the content, this is that second element.

```
<a href="http://c6f.1d3.myftpupload.com/"><div id="Service1" class="linkedbox">
</div></a>
```

Again, what I am trying to do is make the first element linked to a specific page, and keep the `:onhover` effects without editing the markup.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question a bit? What do you need to do, what did you already do, and where is the problem with that solution?

Comment: To clarify, you essentially want the anchor element to cover the first element but to retain the hover effects of the first element?

Comment: @lamelemon Yes, that is exactly what I want to do. You can see what I have on the link below.
http://c6f.1d3.myftpupload.com/5220-2/